# How to populate an Oracle TIMESTAMP WITH ZONE field using Dbunit FlatXmlDataSet

Tags: oracle, dbunit, timestamp-with-timezone, spring-test-dbunit

I am trying to setup data for a DB unit test by populating a table which has columns of type `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE` as follows:

```
<timetable START_TIME="2015-03-01 10.00.00.000000000" END_TIME="2015-03-02 10.00.00.000000000"/>
```

But I keep getting the following exception when I run the test:

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: TIMETABLE.START_TIME -  (Non-uppercase input column: START_TIME) in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive.
    at org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData.getColumnIndex(AbstractTableMetaData.java:117)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractOperation.getOperationMetaData(AbstractOperation.java:89)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:143)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:194)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:66)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:185)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:249)
```

I tried different formats for the timestamp field including the addition of the timezone suffix +XX:XX `2015-03-01 10.00.00.000000000 +00.00` to no avail.
I also tried running the test with the VM argument `-Duser.timezone=UTC` but that didn't help either.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

**EDIT 1**

I noticed the following warnings in the console:

```
2016-05-31 14:54:23 WARN  SQLHelper:429 - TIMETABLE.START_TIME data type (-101, 'TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE') not recognized and will be ignored. See FAQ for more information.
2016-05-31 14:54:23 WARN  SQLHelper:429 - TIMETABLE.END_TIME data type (-101, 'TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE') not recognized and will be ignored. See FAQ for more information.
```

So it looks like Dbunit does not support `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type and ignores it, hence the `NoSuchColumnException` exception

**EDIT 2**

Actually dbunit already supports `TIMESTAMP` data types through `OracleDataTypeFactory` class. The configuration would then look like:

```
<bean id="oracleDataTypeFactory" class="org.dbunit.ext.oracle.OracleDataTypeFactory"/>

<bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConfig" class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseConfigBean">
        <property name="datatypeFactory" ref="oracleDataTypeFactory" />
</bean>
```

Unfortunately, after these config changes the data type problem was still there because dbunit DatabaseConfig.datatypeFactory property was re-set back by DbUnitTestExecutionListener to the default `DefaultDataTypeFactory` which doesn't support TIMESTAMP data types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to load `TIMESTAMP` data by removing Spring-dbunit specific annotations (`@TestExecutionListeners` and `@DbUnitConfiguration`). I still had to use `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`. I then used the 'old' Dbunit way to setup and teardown data and to check data expectations. This is not as concise as Spring-dbunit annotations `@DatabaseSetup`, `@DatabaseTearDown` and `@ExpectedDatabase`, but it does work (See code snippets below). I also kept OracleDataTypeFactory in my test context; this is essential for the TIMESTAMP datatype to be recognised by Dbunit.

I think the issue I faced might be the manifestation of a bug in spring-dbunit Test Execution Listeners. I am particularly suspecting `DbUnitTestExecutionListener`

**Setup:**

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws SQLException, IOException, DataSetException, DatabaseUnitException {    
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("path/to/data_setup.xml");
        FlatXmlDataSetBuilder builder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
        builder.setColumnSensing(true);
        FlatXmlDataSet dataSetup = builder.build(resource.getInputStream());
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbUnitDatabaseConnection, dataSetup);    
    }
```

**Teardown:**

```
@After
    public void tearDown() throws SQLException, IOException, DataSetException, DatabaseUnitException {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("path/to/data_teardown.xml");
        FlatXmlDataSet dataTearDown = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(resource.getInputStream());
        DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL.execute(dbUnitDatabaseConnection, dataTearDown);
    }
```

**Expectation (within test method):**

```
QueryDataSet actualDataSet = new QueryDataSet(dbUnitDatabaseConnection);
actualDataSet.addTable("YOUR_TABLE", "<YOUR_SQL_QUERY>");
FlatXmlDataSet expectedDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new ClassPathResource("path/to/data_expectation.xml").getInputStream());
Assertion.assertEquals(expectedDataSet, actualDataSet);
```